# how to store Random Forest classifiers in shared-memory mode in Parallel Computing in R Programming

Tags: foreach

out <- foreach(.combine = 'list') %dopar% {
rf <- randomForest()
rf
}

Is the variable out in shared memory mode, rather than in fork mode?